# Search Files in Folder in Gedit

Tags: debian, text-editors, gedit

I would like to search files in folder similarly as you can do in Textmate in OSX by pressing `CTRL+Shift f`.

How can you search files in folder in Gedit?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=536733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set search by selection of a word visually

The thread [How-To: Search in files with GEdit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=536733) says

> ```
> 1) open Gedit and enable the "External tools" plugin in Edit >> Preferences >> Plugin
> 2) don't close the dialog but select the plugin and click "Configure plugin" instead
> 3) let's add a new tool with the following properties
>
> Name : Find in files (or whatever you want)
> Description : Find in files (or whatever you want)
> Accelerator (the keybord shortcut) : type <Control><Shift>f (or whatever you want - be sure it's not already used)
> Command :
>
> Code:
>   #!/bin/sh
>   xargs gnome-search-tool --contains
> Input : current selection
> Output: bottom panel
> Scope: all documents
> ```

but this functionality works only if some word is selected giving

[image]

### To get similar Search in Files as in TextMate

Set Input to *Current document* but otherwise as above.